# strings in Quartz Composer

Tags: string, character, quartz-composer

I'm trying to create a patch in Quartz Composer with a real-time typewriter effect, to work together with and interactive old typewriter that I'm developing. 
I can't find the way to concatenate strings in Quartz Composer, what I need is an element, or patch, that allows me to add a character at the end of a string.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can always use a JavaScript patch. Though I thought there was a string concat patch

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String Printer patch.